# Google Action - using Amazon Polly to synthesise text to speech

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-functions, aws-sdk, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I decided to build a Google Action (through Dialogflow V2) that converts text to Speech through Amazon Polly (the voice sounds less robotic than Google's voice).

Now overall this works, usually this results in the requestApplause returning the uploaded location. Sometimes however it doesn't wait for the upload to complete and doesn't play the generated speech. The upload always works though and when trying to trigger the intent the 2nd time it will return the mp3 file like it should

I'm using Nodejs 8, dialogflow and the 'firebase-functions', 'dialogflow-fulfillment' and 'aws-sdk' libraries.

The requestApplause function is called when the user types something and matches the requestApplause intent. I then try to convert the user's query to speech but that doesn't always work.

index.js

```
async function requestApplause(agent) {
        let baseLink = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/link";
        let randomApplauseLink1 = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/link/file.mp3";
        var link = "";
        var text = "";
        let givenName = request.body.queryResult.parameters["given-name"];
        if (givenName !== "") {
            givenName = givenName.toLowerCase();
            link = baseLink + givenName + "-applause.mp3";
            text = "Great f**** job, " + givenName;
            let location = await textToSpeech(text, givenName);
            agent.add("<speak> <audio src='" + link + "'>An error occurred if you heard this -> Great job, name</audio> " +
                "<audio src='" + randomApplauseLink1 + "'>error occurred -> Applause missing :(</audio> </speak>");
             //   + "<audio src='" + randomApplauseLink1 + "'</speak>")
        }
    }


async function textToSpeech(textToSynthesize, givenName) {
        let voiceId = 'Joanna';
        let text = textToSynthesize; //, filename = 'speech-demo-1.mp3', type = 'file' }
        var fileName = '';
        if (givenName !== "") {
            fileName = givenName + "-applause.mp3";
        } else {
            fileName= "random-applause.mp3"
        }
        let type = 'mp3';

        try {
            let audio = await generatePollyAudio(text, voiceId);

            let location = await uploadToS3(audio, fileName);

            return location
        }
        catch (e) {
            if(e.errorCode && e.error) {
                console.log('error textToSpeech function');
            }
        }
    }


async function uploadToS3(data, fileName) {
    let s3params = {
        Body: data.AudioStream,
        Bucket: "<bucket-name>",
        Key: fileName,
        ACL: "public-read"
    };

    var req = await s3.putObject(s3params, function(resp) {
        console.log(arguments);
        console.log('successfully uplaoded....')
    }).send(function(err, data) {
        console.log("FINISHED UPLOADING");
        if (err) {
            console.log('errrrorrrrrr')
        }
    });

}

//Generate audio from Polly and check if output is a Buffer
function generatePollyAudio(text, voiceId) {
    const params = {
        Text: text,
        OutputFormat: 'mp3',
        VoiceId: voiceId
    };

    return polly.synthesizeSpeech(params).promise().then( audio => {
        if (audio.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
            return audio;
        } else throw 'AudioStream is not a Buffer.'
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your question to illustrate how these functions are being called? It looks like you're using the dialogflow-fulfillment library and building a Google Action, is that correct?

Comment: @Prisoner I updated it, I'm indeed using the dialogflow-fulfillment library

Comment: Is there some sort of propagation delay between uploading data to S3 and having it accessible? When you call `await s3.putObject(...).send(...)` is it awaiting the `putObject` or the `send`?

Comment: Does [Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/) really sound more robotic than Google's [Cloud Text-to-Speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/)? Most of [the comparisons I found](https://www.google.com/search?q=Amazon+Polly+vs+google+cloud+text-to-speech) tend to claim the contrary, although I guess it depends on the text. Using the GCP solution might make it easier to integrate, and probably faster since the requests don't need to leave the same datacenter.